# Django: ImportError at/ "doesn't look like a module path

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I solve this problem?

```
Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: first_app doesn't look like a module path

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.5

Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'first_app']

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Comment: Are you sure that `first_app` is a module path? How is your directory layout?

Comment: Yes. 
When I refresh the browser, in my atom terminal I can see this error.

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rifat\miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 13, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: